# import and use function from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

I am trying to import and use the example [given here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html)(saved as `menu.py`) in my `main.py` file.

I am using the file unaltered, except last few line of creating window.
In my `main` file, I  am calling this as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
import urllib
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango
import re
import sys
import urllib
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import menu
from p_SB_SE import parse_wine_systembolagate

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Collection Manager")

        self.set_default_size(1000, 20)
        self.set_border_width(10)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
        self.add(box)
window = MainWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But I am getting error:

```
$python3 main2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 26, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "main2.py", line 24, in __init__
    box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
NameError: name 'menubar' is not defined
```

From tutorials like [this in wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules) I thought this is the proper way of importing modules from different file in same directory.

What I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT** From the comments, I have understood that the problem is to define menubar function in my main code. I tried few way and have not succeded yet.
Can anyone kindly help me?

My goal is to keep my main file short and simple, and that's why I want to move all the menubar related functions to separate file.

This is the `menu.py` function I am trying to call:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango

UI_INFO = """
<ui>
  <menubar name='MenuBar'>
      <menu action='FileNew'>
        <menuitem action='FileNewStandard' />
      <menuitem action='FileOpenStandard' />
      <menuitem action='FileQuit' />
    </menu>
    <menu action='EditMenu'>
      <menuitem action='EditCopy' />
      <menuitem action='EditPaste' />
    </menu>
    <menu action='ChoicesMenu'>
      <menuitem action='Book'/>
      <menuitem action='Wine'/>
    </menu>
  </menubar>
  <popup name='PopupMenu'>
    <menuitem action='EditCopy' />
    <menuitem action='EditPaste' />
  </popup>
</ui>
"""
class MenuWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def menu():
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Menu Example")

        action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("my_actions")

        self.add_file_menu_actions(action_group)
        self.add_edit_menu_actions(action_group)
        self.add_choices_menu_actions(action_group)

        uimanager = self.create_ui_manager()
        uimanager.insert_action_group(action_group)

        menubar = uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")
        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)
        self.add(box)
        button = Gtk.Button("Open")    # Submit button to write to
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

    def add_file_menu_actions(self, action_group):
        action_filemenu = Gtk.Action("FileMenu", "File", None, None)
        action_group.add_action(action_filemenu)

        action_filenewmenu = Gtk.Action("FileNew", None, None, Gtk.STOCK_NEW)
        action_group.add_action(action_filenewmenu)

        action_new = Gtk.Action("FileNewStandard", "_New",
            "Create a new file", Gtk.STOCK_NEW)
        action_new.connect("activate", self.on_menu_file_new_generic)
        action_group.add_action_with_accel(action_new, None)

        action_group.add_actions([
            ("FileNewFoo", None, "New Foo", None, "Create new foo",
             self.on_menu_file_new_generic),
            ("FileNewGoo", None, "_New Goo", None, "Create new goo",
             self.on_menu_file_new_generic),
        ])

        action_filequit = Gtk.Action("FileQuit", None, None, Gtk.STOCK_QUIT)
        action_filequit.connect("activate", self.on_menu_file_quit)
        action_group.add_action(action_filequit)

    def add_edit_menu_actions(self, action_group):
        action_group.add_actions([
            ("EditMenu", None, "Edit"),
            ("EditCopy", Gtk.STOCK_COPY, None, None, None,
             self.on_menu_others),
            ("EditPaste", Gtk.STOCK_PASTE, None, None, None,
             self.on_menu_others),
            ("EditSomething", None, "Something", "<control><alt>S", None,
             self.on_menu_others)
        ])

    def add_choices_menu_actions(self, action_group):
        action_group.add_action(Gtk.Action("ChoicesMenu", "Choices", None,
            None))

        action_group.add_radio_actions([
            ("ChoiceOne", None, "One", None, None, 1),
            ("ChoiceTwo", None, "Two", None, None, 2)
        ], 1, self.on_menu_choices_changed)

        three = Gtk.ToggleAction("ChoiceThree", "Three", None, None)
        three.connect("toggled", self.on_menu_choices_toggled)
        action_group.add_action(three)

    def create_ui_manager(self):
        uimanager = Gtk.UIManager()

        # Throws exception if something went wrong
        uimanager.add_ui_from_string(UI_INFO)

        # Add the accelerator group to the toplevel window
        accelgroup = uimanager.get_accel_group()
        self.add_accel_group(accelgroup)
        return uimanager

    def on_menu_file_new_generic(self, widget):
        print("A File|New menu item was selected.")

    def on_menu_file_quit(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_menu_others(self, widget):
        print("Menu item " + widget.get_name() + " was selected")

    def on_menu_choices_changed(self, widget, current):
        print(current.get_name() + " was selected.")

    def on_menu_choices_toggled(self, widget):
        if widget.get_active():
            print(widget.get_name() + " activated")
        else:
            print(widget.get_name() + " deactivated")

    def on_button_press_event(self, widget, event):
        # Check if right mouse button was preseed
        if event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS and event.button == 3:
            self.popup.popup(None, None, None, None, event.button, event.time)
            return True # event has been handled
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the import, `menubar` variable is just not there in the original file.

Comment: Please see line 58 of the imported file

Comment: @BaRud: you imported `menu`, not `menubar`. Did you mean to use `menu.menubar`?

Comment: @BaRud: the tutorial defines `menubar` as part of the `MenuExampleWindow.__init__` method; it assigns it as `menubar = uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")`. Your code never does that.

Comment: Oh... I understand. Can you please show me how to define that in my main code?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: My main code is just a window now. I am trying to add a menubar to it.